# How to read body of response from fetch call

Tags: javascript, node.js, fetch-api

Should probably mention I am new to fetch API, still learning. So sorry if this seems like a basic question. Anyways. To sum up my code, I have a fetch that runs once a button is clicked, it takes the content of an input element, and posts that to my server. Once my server validates it, it sends a response as `res.send("success")`. I want to be able to `console.log` that, or run an if else statement. Here is the code:

Front end

```
<script>
  document.getElementById('checktradeurl').addEventListener('click', setTradeURL);
  function setTradeURL(){
    var tradeofferURL = document.getElementById('tradeurl').value
    fetch('/api/tradeurl/', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify({url:tradeofferURL})
    })
    .then(response=>response.json()
    )
    .then((res)=>{
      console.log(res)
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err)
    })
    };
</script>
```

Backend

```
router.post('/api/tradeurl/', async (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body.url)
    let link = req.body.url;
    if (URL.parse(link, true).query.partner && URL.parse(link, true).query.token) {
        var sid = new SteamID.fromIndividualAccountID(URL.parse(link, true).query.partner);
        var sid64 = sid.getSteamID64();
        var token = URL.parse(link, true).query.token;
        console.log(sid64);
        console.log(token)
        var key = process.env.apiKey
        let url = `https://api.steampowered.com/IEconService/GetTradeHoldDurations/v1/?key=${key}&steamid_target=${sid64}&trade_offer_access_token=${token}`
        console.log(url)
        fetch(url).then((data) => {
            return responsecode = data.headers.get('x-eresult')
        }).then(code => {
            if (code == 1) {
                res.send("SUCCESS")
            }
        })
    }
    // var key = process.env.apiKey
    // res.sendStatus(200);
});
```

Comment: With `res.send("SUCCESS")` you are sending `SUCCESS` plainly as text, there is no JSON anywhere. So you'd need `response.text()` and not `response.json()` on the client, otherwise you'd just get a JSON parsing error. Actually I'm surprised you didn't write that you got such an error! Which makes me wonder: What result _do_ you get? Please include a description of _how_ it doesn't work.

Comment: Oof my bad. Totally forgot to mention I get an invalid json token error. I don't remember it exactly because I have already changed my code. Thanks for the help!